# How to find a closed form solution of E[Max(X,Y)]?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expectation

There are 2 Random Variables X and Y.

X ~ N(a,b) and Y ~ N(c,d). X and Y are correlated with a correlation coefficient of p.

How do I find a closed form solution of E[MAX(X,Y)]?

Whichever way I look at it, I am not able to get rid of the randomness in the solution.

My sol:- E[MAX(X,Y)] = X* P(X>Y) + Y*P(Y>X)

But if I do this I will get an answer in terms of X and Y which are still Random.

Comment: I think what you are attempting to write is
$$E[\max(X,Y)] = E[X \mid X>Y] P(X>Y) + E[Y \mid Y>X] P(Y>X).$$

Comment: @angryavian - Yes that makes sense. I had it wrong. P(X>Y) I can  find. But how do I work with E[X|X>Y]?